# Does anyone have a G pot graph?

Tags: potentiometer

How does the G pot (or Graphic pot) graph look like?  Does anyone have a graph?

Is it more of a linear type or audio pot?

Tried searching on Google but couldn't find the graph.

G Pot = W pot

[how to make a W potentiometer from a log or linear pot?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75879/how-to-make-a-w-potentiometer-from-a-log-or-linear-pot)

Comment: I've never head of a "G pot". Different pot tapers are specified by manufacturers, and there are some conventions, see here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69267/how-to-know-whether-a-potentiometer-is-a-linear-potentiometer-or-audio-potentiom/69271#69271 But, no "G" there. I'd need some more context around where you saw this "G pot" to know what it might mean.

Comment: @PhilFrost Apparently that answer is not definitive: See [this link](http://www.planetz.com/potentiometer-tapers-graphed/) which mentions "*... typical A (audio/log), C (reverse audio/log), B (linear), and W (s curve) tapers.   Less common are the K, D, and **G** tapers.*". Several other references if you search for "graphic taper" - but sadly no graphic illustration of graphic tapers!

Comment: [Another reference](http://www.generalguitargadgets.com/faq/40-technical-questions/174-what-does-pot-taper-mean-audio-log-linear) to the term "*G taper*", again without specifics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is snip showing a "G" curve from this [Panasonic document](http://www.panasonic.com/industrial/components/pdf/AOK0000PE1.pdf) (warning - opens pdf)
[image]

Comment: +1, good find - I spent a bit of time trawling through a plethora of search results, but with no luck!

Comment: Must be a Panasonic thing. I think the "(4B)" is a hint that everyone else calls it 4B. [Alps seems to call it "W (4B)"](http://www.alps.com/products/WebObjects/catalog.woa/E/HTML/Potentiometer/RotaryPotentiometers/RK09K/RK09K_common.html#Resistance%20Taper)

Comment: Thank you also found out that G pot is also known as W pot